# Regex: Scrub a YouTube URL within a string, leaving only the YouTube video code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a text that contains a YouTube URL.  I need to remove all portions of the link, except for the YouTube video code.  The URL may be surrounded by blank space or nothing; no non-blank characters will adjoin the URL.

SAMPLE:

```
$txt = "This text contain this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8ri14rw32c&rel=0 and so on..."
```

EXTRACTING ID:

```
$pattern = '#(?<=v=|v\/|vi=|vi\/|youtu.be\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

EXPECTED:

```
Array
(
    [0] = "This text contain this link b8ri14rw32c and so on..."
)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Your regex does not match your explanation. Show before and after samples with all those _alternations_ in context.

Comment: @sln `$pattern = '#(?<=v=|v\/|vi=|vi\/|youtu.be\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $txt, $matches);
print_r( $matches);`

Comment: Since you are using the pound sign as a delimiter, you don't need to escape the forward slash. `#(?<=v=|v/|vi=|vi/|youtu.be/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}#`

Comment: Thank you for the improve.. how about the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this pattern to match:

```
https:\/\/(?:www.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?vi?[=\/])?(\w{11})(?:&\w+=[^&\s]*)*
```

There is exactly one capture in this expression, and it's for the YouTube video code.  This capture can be used with a regex replace to replace the entire link text with just the captured video code.

This regex will work with these format YouTube URLs:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8ri14rw32c&rel=0
https://youtu.be/Rk_sAHh9s08
```

Other YouTube URL formats have not been tested, but could easily be supported if needed.

This PHP code will test this regexp replacement using `preg_replace`:

```
$txt = "This text contain this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8ri14rw32c&rel=0 and so on...";
$pattern = "/https:\/\/(?:www.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?vi?[=\/])?(\w{11})(?:&\w+=[^&\s]*)*/";
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1', $txt);
```

Comment: While executing this code on PHP 7.0 showing waring and result. preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash. please improve your code.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, the following should work for normal YouTube links (unshortened).

```
https?:\/\/[^\s]+[?&]v=([^&\s]+)[^\s]*
```

Replace with `\1`
(Capturing group 1)

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/lY5vZ4/2)

Comment: I already explain that i have the youtube id.... i need to remove the link that contain the id!

Comment: @degeaba see my updated answer, using the regex replace feature.